# Sitecore website deployment to Azure

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, azure-deployment

I have created a website using Sitecore and now i want to deploy it to Azure. Can you please suggest the way how can i do this?

I tried differed ways but none worked for me.

- I tried creating VM but no installation is there so how to proceed
- Then tried deploying Sitecore website as Azure cloud service, bt it throws error when connecting from visual tudio

Please help as possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can found Azure documentation and downloads on the Sitecore dev website:
[Sitecore Azure](https://doc.sitecore.net/cloud/azure)

Also see the [Sitecore Azure Compatibility Table](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/880886)

Answer (score 0):

Please also read next article for **compatibility** check - will your bespoke solution fit Azure? http://techitpro.com/sitecore-azure/

10 Considerations for a Successful Sitecore Azure Implementation - A Step-by-Step Guide: http://www.perficient.com/securedocs/1841191041051161013211297112101114115.pdf

Also consider your hosting options and the way you are going to do the **deployment** (both code and packages). There is a good article on that:

http://blog.petersondave.com/sitecore/azure/Alternate-Sitecore-8-Azure-Deployment-Options/ 
http://www.cmsbestpractices.com/choosing-the-right-hosting-option-for-sitecore/